# Link phone Authentication to google and Facebook Provider on Web

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

```
const onSignInSubmit = (e) => {
```

After successfull Phone authentication , if a user login with google i want to check if user is already exist with the account

Comment: I want to check if user is already logged in with phone provider and directly logins

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the use-case. Are you asking [how to link multiple providers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/account-linking) to a single account?

Comment: yes I am using phone and google and facebook auth so if user login via phone so next time if he login via google it should not create another user , the user should be same with which phone number created

Comment: The page I linked shows how to link credentials for multiple providers to a single account. Did you try that?

Comment: but when i sign in via google should i have to prompt the user for phone number to link the phone number

Comment: No. Instead you should first detect that they're signed in already, then ask them for the Google credentials, and link those to the existing phone number auth account.

Comment: can u help me with the code ?